# How do I automatically sort methods by header?

Tags: c++, header, code-structure

It is good style to sort methods in header files in the same order as in the .cpp file, but often this order gets crude during development.

How can I reorder the methods in the cpp file to the order given in the header file?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a code beautifier.  What platform are you on, Windows or unix?

Comment: I think you're sweating the *really* small stuff.

Comment: i'm working on linux, but can also use windows. And Of course it's a really small thing but a nice to have which increases the code readabilty.

Comment: In most cases it will not improve readability over, say an IDE that can search for methods for you... or even a plain search in the file. This is *really really really small* stuff.

Comment: One of the things I've always found deficient in languages that support the notion of header files is the fact that there's no standard way to put everything in one source file and generate the header from it.  You really shouldn't have to maintain two copies of your declarations.  And to answer your question, the tool I'd use to do that is called an "intern."  :-)

Comment: It's not really two copies of declarations -- one certainly is declaration, but the other is *definition*.

Comment: I ask Rider to open a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-33776/Sort-methods-in-Implementation-files-.cpp-based-on-order-of-their-declarations-header-files-.h

Answer (score 1):

I've found it effective to use a graphical diff tool to show the header and source file side by side to keep the documentation in sync and make sure everything's in the same order. (My employer bought me Araxis Merge, so that's what I use, but there are a variety of free and commercial tools that accomplish the same thing on a variety of platforms.)

This might be easier with a procedural C or C++ file, as opposed to an object-oriented C++ file where class member functions would have a different indentation level in the header than in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
The headline says: sort methods in cpp file by header
The body says:  sort methods in header files in the same order as in the cpp file
```

Isn’t that contradictory? :-)

While is possible to edit the header or source files either by some tool or by hand, in real life, **it is very hard to enforce/maintain that order**.

My approach is to “view” the method names in alphabetical order. That is achievable by running [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html) on the files. In the doxygen config file, the following two options might be useful

```
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modeller (such as Umbrello) to model your classes and generate the appropriate code.